# Reading from Page Albums to integrate website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a public website and I also have a corresponding Facebook page. I do restorations so my public website needs to have images related to each restoration. I already keep an album for each restoration within Facebook and I would like to leverage those same images instead of duplicating the effort. I would like to use the JavaScript SDK to read the albums from my page. I can successfully do this via the Graph API explorer /{pageId}/Albums using the token generator. However, users visiting my public website should not be prompted to login to Facebook. Is there any way I can generate a token that will allow me to read and display images from these albums without requiring them to login?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you probably want so solve server-side, not client-side, because it would expose your token publicly.

If your album is public you can easily generate an app token server side and read the images from the album using that token.